# What is the real data flow of redux?

Tags: javascript

Redux data flow is defined as:
Action -> Reducers -> Store -> React components -> Action

but i've seen some define the data flow as:
Action creators -> Store -> Reducers -> Store -> View -> Action creators

Which one is the correct one?

Comment: first. Action creators, I believe, help you reduce boilerplate code

Comment: So why is there a command store.dispatch(action)?

Comment: dispatch is a method on store that fires an action? https://redux.js.org/api/store

Answer (score 0):

Actions are the important part. An action is an object with a type property, and possibly additional properties with data. You kick things off by dispatching an action:

```
dispatch({
  type: 'ADD_USER',
  payload: 'tim'
});
```

Often, there will be actions which are related to eachother, and that's where action creators come in. An action creator is a helper method which creates an action. For example, this is an action creator:

```
const addUser = (user) => {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_USER',
    payload: user,
  }
}
```

This lets you dispatch an action using code like the following

```
dispatch(addUser('tim'));
```

Using this style can make the code more concise, while also ensuring that all actions of the same type will look the same (ie, you'll never have to remember "did i call it action.payload, or action.user"?). But if you don't see a need for this, that's fine, you can do it longhand as well.